# What to use as electrovalve?

Tags: rcservo, mechanism, valve

I want do make following installation (blowing bottle tops as music instrument):

```
V - valve
B - bottle


 ___________________
|mini air compressor|
 -------------------
         |
   ______|_______
  |  |  |  |  |  |
  V  V  V  V  V  V
  |  |  |  |  |  |
  B  B  B  B  B  B
```

And I want to use and rc servo as electro valve (throttle) to control air flow for each bottle. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you won't need a servo.  The more common way to throttle a flow is to use [pneumatic solenoid valves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_valve) (which are either open or closed) and control them with [PWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation).

See (for example) [this link](http://www.tlxtech.com/understanding-solenoids/theory-operation/pwm-solenoid-theory).  This is also how the boost controller in many cars works.

Comment: this is quite good solution. and I'll consider it ... but it's not the cheapest one :), rc servo is still cheapest and easiest to use (just connect it to uC and you're ready to go)

Comment: What are you using for a valve that makes it cheaper than the industry standard?